# Remove ANSI codes when storing script output

Tags: linux, logging, command-line, terminal, ansi-escape

Some programs makes beautiful progressbars and stuff using ANSI escape sequences. That's nice.

What's not nice though is that if i put the output of that kind of program into a file and then try to view it it's filled with strange escape sequences.

Is there a way to strip away all the ANSI codes while logging?

I usually log the output of a script this way:

```
./script >> /tmp/output.log
```

Comment: can't you just capture the output of the programs to separate log files. Put another way, why do you *have* to use script? Good luck!

Comment: The script is not a logging-script, the script/program is what uses the ANSI-sequences. It has normal output too and it's that normal output i wan't to store. The ansi-sequences should be stripped away.

Comment: This should be moved to unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
$ TERM=dumb ./script >> /tmp/output.log
```

If that doesn't work, it's because the ANSI codes have been hard-coded into the script, so there is no easy way to remove them.  If it does, it's because it's doing the right thing, delegating things like pretty output to `libncurses` or similar, so that when you change the `TERM` variable, the library no longer sends those codes.

Answer (score 0):

use [`ansifilter`](https://gitlab.com/saalen/ansifilter):

```
$ ./script | ansifilter >> /tmp/output.log
```

Comment: Without more information, this is rather lackluster. Where would one obtain this software? Does it do anything more or different than the other answer here?

Comment: The tool is included in various Linux distributions, for example Debian and Ubuntu (https://packages.debian.org/trixie/ansifilter).
Some documentation reference might be helpful https://github.com/andre-simon/ansifilter